# My wordpress sub pages in live server not following the template hierachy ,my local server does

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site it contain many pages and each page have 5 sub pages.These sub pages are created by code using WordPress `wp_insert_post function`.  I have also created post meta for page template for these sub pages.  Sub pages having these names like player,viewer,game,role,news.  So each page have sub pages with these names.

My code for creating sub page is here,

```
 'wp_insert_post(
    array(                                                                        
      'comment_status'  =>  'closed',
      'post_author'     =>  $author_id,                                                                                
      'post_name'       =>  '',
      'post_content'    =>  '',                                                                         
      'post_title'      =>  'viewer',                                                                                                                                      
      'post_status'     =>  'publish',
      'post_type'       =>  'page',                                                                        
      'post_parent'    => $post_id                                                        
)'
```

My sites page hierarchy is as follows

> 'testsite.com/page1/player'
>
> 'testsite.com/page2/player'
>
> 'testsite.com/page3/player'
>
> 'testsite.com/page1/viewer'
>
> 'testsite.com/page2/viewer'
>
> 'testsite.com/page3/viewer'

My issue is that in my local server sub pages takes the custom template and works as expected.  In each sub pages I am getting correct post ID .

When I moved this same code to live server WordPress Its sub pages not taking the correct custom template.  Sub pages takes single.php page in live server.Also for each sub pages it displays the first created post ID as the selected sub pages `ID`, for example when I take `testsite.com/page22/player` I get the `ID` of this sub page as the first created sub page.  In my local server I got the correct page `ID` in the same page.

In my local server sub pages accepts `page-{slug}.php` templates and custom templates but in live server it won't take these templates.

Please help me to find the actual reason for these.Also Is there any method like we can force the sub pages to take the custom template?

Comment: do you use the same version of WordPress on live and on local servers ?

Comment: Yes .Same version of wordpress.